# Thunderbird 2 Grippers

Tags: thunderbirds

In the series, Thunderbird 2 regularly uses the magnetic grabs.  I was wondering whether these are standard to *all* pods, or just some (refer to answer from [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51366/contents-of-each-pod-for-thunderbird-2) question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://thunderbirds.wikia.com/wiki/Pod_machines) article, the magnetic grabs are only ever used with Pod 2.